# MPI_File_set_view for parallel file output using custom MPI_Datatype as filetype

Tags: c++, mpi

I am struggeling to understand how MPI_File_set_view works, especially the 4th parameter confuses me.

> int MPI_File_set_view(MPI_File fh, MPI_Offset disp, MPI_Datatype etype, MPI_Datatype filetype, const char *datarep, MPI_Info info)

Lets assume I have n threads, each of them has a char array of length 10 called "v", all entries of this array are equal to the threads ID. So

> thread0: v={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
>
> thread1: v={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
>
> thread2: v={2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}
>
> ...

Now I want to write a binary file containing the values of these arrays in the following order:

> file = thread0.v[0], thread1.v[0], thread2.v[0], ..., thread0.v[1], thread1.v[1], thread2.v[1], ..., thread0.v[2], thread1.v[2], thread2.v[2], ...

As far as I understood I have to construct a MPI_Datatype for the  filetype parameter, which is of size [sizeof(char)*n], where there is a "hole" of size [sizeof(char)*threadID] before the MPI_Char data and another "hole" of size [sizeof(char)*(n-threadID-1)] after the data. I think this is the part, where I am making the mistake.

My code looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<mpi.h>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int myId;
    int numProcs;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numProcs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myId);
    
    int size=100;
    char v[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        v[i]=myId;
    }
    
    int blocklen[numProcs];
    MPI_Aint disp[numProcs];
    MPI_Datatype type[numProcs];
    for(int i=0;i<numProcs;i++){
        blocklen[i]=1;
        disp[i]=sizeof(char)*myId;
        type[i]=MPI_CHAR;
    }
    
    MPI_Datatype mytype;
    MPI_Type_create_struct(numProcs, blocklen, disp, type, &mytype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mytype);
    
    MPI_File fh;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "binfile", MPI_MODE_WRONLY | MPI_MODE_CREATE, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
    MPI_File_set_view(fh, 0, MPI_BYTE, mytype, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
    MPI_File_write(fh, v, size, MPI_BYTE, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    
    MPI_File_close(&fh);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

When I hexdump the file "binfile" I get this (using 4 threads):

> $ hd binfile
>
> 00000000  00 01 01 01 01 01 01 01  01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 |................|
>
> 00000010  01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01  01 01 02 03 |............|
>
> 0000001c

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: You are constructing the datatype in a wrong way. Use [`MPI_Type_create_subarray`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.10/man3/MPI_Type_create_subarray.3.php) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, with your answer I was able to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Hristo Iliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374437/hristo-iliev)s comment I was able to solve my problem.
The function

> int MPI_Type_create_subarray(int ndims, const int array_of_sizes[],
>   const int array_of_subsizes[], const int array_of_starts[], int order,
>   MPI_Datatype oldtype, MPI_Datatype *newtype)

does the trick. array_of_sizes defines the size of the new datatype. array_of_subsizes defines the size of the part, which is not part of the "holes" and array_of_starts defines where the "non-hole" part starts.

For anyone interested this is the working code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<mpi.h>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int myId;
    int numProcs;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numProcs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myId);

    int size=100;
    char v[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        v[i]=myId;
    }

    int array_of_sizes[1];
    array_of_sizes[0]=numProcs;
    int array_of_subsizes[1];
    array_of_subsizes[0]=1;
    int array_of_starts[1];
    array_of_starts[0]=myId;


    MPI_Datatype mytype;
    MPI_Type_create_subarray(1,array_of_sizes, array_of_subsizes, array_of_starts, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_BYTE, &mytype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mytype);

    MPI_File fh;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "binfile", MPI_MODE_WRONLY | MPI_MODE_CREATE, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
    MPI_File_set_view(fh, 0, MPI_BYTE, mytype, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
    MPI_File_write(fh, v, size, MPI_BYTE, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    MPI_File_close(&fh);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```